# Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, build

I want to build an app for macOS in flutter using vs code but there is an error like this, I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/handikadjatidharma/honda_lucky_draw/macos/Runner/Release.entitlements'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

```
** BUILD FAILED **
```

this is the content of Release.entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

what should I do with an error like this?